# Time interval of existence of an SDE solution with locally Lipschitz drift

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the stochastic ODE $$
dX = F(X) \, dt + dB
$$
where $B$ is Brownian motion. If the drift $F$ is locally Lipschitz, then the solution exists and is unique over $[0,T]$ where $T$ is an "almost surely positive" random time.

My question is, can we find a measure 1 set and a deterministic constant $C$, such that on this measure 1 set the random time $T$>$C$?  This seems stronger than saying "$T$ is almost surely positive" random time.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer to your question is no.  For instance, consider $$
d X(t) = X(t)^2 dt + \sigma d B(t) \;, \quad X(0) = x_0 \;.
$$  In this case, the drift $F(x) = x^2$ is locally Lipschitz since its derivative is locally bounded.  When $\sigma =0$, we obtain the ODE $$ 
\dot{x}(t) = x(t)^2 \;, \quad x(0) = x_0 
$$ with solution $$
x(t) = \frac{x_0}{1-x_0 t} 
$$ which is well-defined for $0 \le t < 1/x_0$.  Thus, for any $C>0$ and $x_0 < 1/C$, the ODE solution exists and is unique over $[0,C]$.

The situation is different for the SDE: in any time interval, there is a nonzero (but possibly tiny) probability that $X(t)$ reaches a state where the drift dominates. From this point forward, with high probability, the SDE solution evolves like the ODE solution but with a *random* initial condition. Hence, the solution is defined up to a random time.

This phenomenon is illustrated in the figure below with $x_0 = 1/10$ and $C=10$.  In red is the ODE solution for comparison.  In different shades of grey are ten independent realizations of $X(t)$.

[image]