# Weak uniqueness of an SDE with locally Lipschitz drift and additive noise?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the $d$-dimensional SDE, $d > 1$,

$$dX_t = b(X_t) \, dt + \sqrt 2 \, dW_t$$

where

- $b$ is locally Lipschitz such that $|b(x)| \le C |x|^2$ for $x \in \mathbb R^d$.
- $W$ is a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion.

> Do you know some references about the weak uniqueness of above SDE?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288996/time-interval-of-existence-of-an-sde-solution-with-locally-lipschitz-drift

Comment: @user479223 I don't see how your link answers the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For d=1, this is covered in Karatzas-Shreve in the section on Feller-tests. In particular, in exercise 5.38, they have that if $$\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon}b^{2}(y)dy<\infty,$$

then $dX_{t}=b(X_{t})dt+dW_{t}$ has a weak solution up to explosion time $S$ and it is unique in probability law. The main idea is using Girsanov theorem (hence that square-integrability condition).

For $d\geq 1$, see ["Strong solutions of stochastic equations with singular time dependent drift"](https://bibos.math.uni-bielefeld.de/preprints/03-11-131.pdf) and ["strong solutions of stochastic differential equations with square integrable drift"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.03157.pdf), where again they require integrability: there exists open set $Q\subset\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$

$$\int \left(\int |b(t,x)1_{Q}(t,x)|^{p} dx\right)^{q/p}dt<\infty,$$

for some $p\geq 2, q>2$ with $\frac{d}{2}+\frac{2}{q}<1$.

Comment: The mentioned exercise deals with the case $d=1$. Are you aware of any result when $d>1$?

Comment: @Akira I added some references.

Comment: It seems from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT5Pg.png) screenshot (of the first paper) that the following integrability condition is sufficient, i.e., $$\int_0^n \left(\int_{B(0, n)} |b(t,x)|^{p} dx\right)^{q}dt<\infty, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.$$ Here $B(0, n)$ is the open ball centered at $0$ with radius $n$. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @Akira, right, I just wrote a simplification of that.

Comment: By the definition of the space $L_q \_ L_p$, I guess you meant the superscript $q/p$ rather than $q$ in the integral.

Comment: @Akira but to be clear, these solutions can blow up in finite time eg. $dX_{t}=X^2_{t}dt+dB_{t}$ blows up in finite time. So all the above results are only valid up to the explosion time.